# Как сделать ListView как в VK?

Tags: android

Как сделать ListView как в VK?

Чтобы пролистывалось все.
Вот мой код

```
public class News extends Fragment{
View view;
int offset=0, count=10;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
BaseAdapter baseAdapter;
NewsGSON newsGSON;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag2,container,false);
    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setTitle("Загрузка данных");
    progressDialog.show();

    VKRequest vkRequest = new VKApiWall().get(VKParameters.from(
            VKApiConst.OWNER_ID,"-21314891",
            VKApiConst.COUNT,count,
            "filter","owner",
            VKApiConst.EXTENDED,1,
            VKApiConst.OFFSET,offset));

    vkRequest.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);
            newsGSON=new Gson().fromJson(response.responseString,NewsGSON.class);
            new Async().execute();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(VKError error) {
            super.onError(error);
            Log.e("response vkRequest = ", "error");
        }
    });

    return view;
}

class Async extends AsyncTask{

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        baseAdapter=new BaseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return count;
            }
            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.frag2_adap,parent,false);
                TextView text1= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                TextView text2= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
                TextView title= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
                ImageView imageAva= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_ava);
                ImageView image= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

                ImageView imageLike= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_like);
                ImageView imageComment= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_comment);
                TextView textLike= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_like);
                TextView textComment= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_comment);

                text1.setText(newsGSON.getResponse().getGroups().get(0).getName());

                Date date = new Date( newsGSON.getResponse().getItems().get(position).getDate()*1000L );
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                sdf.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "GMT+5" ) );
                String d = sdf.format( date );
                text2.setText(d);

                title.setText(newsGSON.getResponse().getItems().get(position).getText());
                textLike.setText(String.valueOf(newsGSON.getResponse().getItems().get(position).getLikes().getCount()));
                textComment.setText(String.valueOf(newsGSON.getResponse().getItems().get(position).getComments().getCount()));

                Picasso.with(getActivity())
                        .load(newsGSON.getResponse().getItems().get(position).getAttachments().get(0).getPhoto().getPhoto_604())
                        .resize(300,300)
                        .into(image);

                Picasso.with(getActivity())
                        .load(newsGSON.getResponse().getGroups().get(0).getPhoto_100())
                        .resize(70,70)
                        .into(imageAva);

                if (position==10) {
                    offset=3;

                }
                return convertView;
            }
        };
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);
        ListView listView= (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(baseAdapter);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

Незнаю как сделать чтобы если позиция пролистывания >10. То AsyncTask запустился заново. Чтобы получить остальные 10 элементов со смещением в 10.

Как сделать не знаю. Мозг трещит уже

Мож лучше либу качнуть какую нить?

Comment: https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20endless%20list